# How to call a view based on radio button selection in django

Tags: html, django, radio-button

I am using Django for my project, I am completely new to web development and Django.

Here is my requirement:

1. I will be having 2 radio buttons, and based on the selection of radio button, few check boxes should be displayed.
2. User will choose the check boxes and click on GO, now some script executes in the back end and a heat map will be displayed for selected check boxes.

Is it possible to do the task1 using Django? If yes, how can we achieve that?

Thanks,
Yogi.

Comment: what have you done for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most would approach this with JavaScript but it can actually be done rather easily with HTML/CSS.

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="show" name="group">
<input type="checkbox" id="reveal" name="group">
```

CSS

```
#reveal {
    display: none;
}

input#show:checked ~ #reveal{
    display: block;
}
```

Simply add the HTML to one of your Django templates and the CSS to your static CSS file in Django.

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/px4qebyc/

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
This is what I have been looking for.
but seeing 2 minor issues:
1. If I select radio button1 and choose couple of check boxes, then I change my mind and select radio button2, still check boxes under radio button1 are selected, I can see the checkboxes in both radio boxes in request.GET on Django.

2. If I give some label for the checkbox, that is being displayed even if I don't select the radio button.